# Carriage return vs newline in vim

Tags: vim, newlines

In vim, when I opened a file, I wanted to add two empty lines at the end of each current line. I used the following switch:

```
%s/$/\n\n/
```

Apparently, this does not work, but what does work is:

```
%s/$/\r\r/
```

I thought \r is a Windows feature? Would anyone be able to explain a bit more.

Comment: Possibly same on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/71323/how-to-replace-a-character-for-a-newline-in-vim

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [vim docs on patterns](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/%5Cr):

> \r    matches <CR>
>
> \n    matches an end-of-line - 
>     When matching in a string instead of
>   buffer text a literal newline
>     character is matched.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71417/why-is-r-a-newline-for-vim

Comment: Argh, I blindly copypasted the original answer from Stack Overflow. Wait for it... fixed!

Comment: Yeah I saw this answer over there. Not sure where it was pointing to. If you figure it out I'd suggest editing the SO Q as well.

Comment: @slm I've fixed both my post and the post on SO :)

Comment: Nice, I couldn't find that, good detective work!

Comment: You don't have to do strike throughs, the edit history contains the original version.

Comment: Your answer would imply that `\n` would match a newline character in a buffer, since it's an LF and not a CR.

Comment: Ok, so the takeaway for me is vim is weird. Gosh, i should've switched to emacs when i had the chance.

Comment: @SandeepY yeah, at least this is weird, but that doesn't make `vim` a bad editor ;)

Comment: BTW: some sites on the Internet suggest that `vim` uses `\r` for a newline instead of `\n` because the latter expands to a null byte when replacing, so that users wouldn't confuse a `\n` newline with a `\n` null byte.

Answer (score 4):

As @MartinvonWittich has stated you want to use `\r`. You can also use the keyboard combination:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> which typically get's display as `^M` when typed.

```
%s/$/^M^M/
```

Here's some additionally useful info on `vim` with respect to search and replace:

#### When searching:

- `.`, `*`, \, `[`, `]`, `^`, and `$` are metacharacters.
- `+`, `?`, |, `{`, `}`, `(`, and `)` must be escaped to use their special function.
- `\/` is `/` (use backslash + forward slash to search for forward slash)
- `\t` is tab, `\s` is whitespace
- `\n` is newline, `\r` is CR (carriage return = Ctrl-M = ^M)
- `\{#\}` is used for repetition. `/foo.\{2\}` will match foo and the two following characters. The `\` is not required on the closing } so `/foo.\{2}` will do the same thing.
- `\(foo\)` makes a backreference to foo. Parenthesis without escapes are literally matched. Here the `\` is required for the closing `\`).

#### When replacing:

- `\r` is newline, `\n` is a null byte (0x00).
- `\&` is ampersand (& is the text that matches the search pattern).
- `\1` inserts the text of the first backreference. `\2` inserts the second backreference, and so on.

#### References

- [Vim: \n vs. \r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/350661/vim-n-vs-r)
- [Why is \r a newline for Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71417/why-is-r-a-newline-for-vim)
- [Search and replace](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_and_replace)

Comment: You're not really explaining why it's `\r` rather than `\n`. I think the answer boils down to “Vim is weird”, but there may be some now-forgotten historical reason.

Comment: @Gilles - In researching this all information I can find seems circular as to why `\r` is a `<CR>`. It just is. But I would agree with your comment that it's weird.

Comment: The worst is that it's different when replacing. So to change <CR> to newlines you unintuitively use `:%s/\r/\r/f`